# Order of subgroup generated by two commuting nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Q: Suppose $G$ is a group, $a,b \in  G$ such that $e,a$ and $b$ are all distinct, $a^2 = b^2 = e$, and $ab = ba$. Prove $\langle a,b\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order exactly $4$.

My thoughts:

I believe   $\langle a , b \rangle := \{a^x*b^y: x,y  \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Every element is its own inverse.

The claim is that $\langle a, b\rangle = \{e, a, b , ab\}$, i.e. this is the Klein-four group and not some other group with these properties.

There is some crucial thought that isn't entering my thought process.

Comment: Your description if $\langle a,b\rangle$ has a big problem: You seem to have two operations there, and the group only has one.

Comment: So should x,y $ \in $ Z?

Comment: where did $Z$ come from? do you mean set of integers...

Comment: Is it given that $ab=ba$ and $a^2=b^2=e$ or just $a^2=b^2=e$

Comment: Think about {${e,a,b,ab}$} and if you have two operation then you have ring!! your description is really problematic.

Comment: Come on guys, don't be so harsh! OP means $\langle a,b\rangle=\{a^xb^y: x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: It gives that ab = ba and $a^2 = b^2$ = e.
Yeah integers.

Comment: @Adam, see my previous comment, the powers of $a$ and $b$ cannot get beyond $2$, since the order of those elements is $2$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Not true, really. $(12)^2=(13)^2=1$ but these elements don't commute in $S_3$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : Oh yeah... a valid counter example... I was trying to say group in which each element is of order $2$ is abelian and i messed it up :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Aha. In fact note $\langle (12),(13)\rangle =S_3$ has order $6$. So the hypothesis that $ab=ba$ is essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SPOILER** $\langle a,b\rangle$ consists of all products from the set $\{a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}\}$. Since $ab=ba$; any product of $a$s  and $b$s can be written as $a^mb^n$ for some integers $m,n$ -- that is, we may rearrange any word, say $abbabbaba$, to bring the $a$ to the front and the $b$s to the back -- and since $a^{-1}=a$ and $b^{-1}=b$, we can assume $m,n\geqslant 0$. Since $a^2=b^2=e$, we may write $m=2k+j$, $j=0,1$ and $n=2u+i$, $i=0,1$ we have $a^m=(a^2)^ka^j=a^j$, the same goes for $b$. We conclude any element in $\langle a,b\rangle$ can be written as $a^jb^i$ with $i,j=0,1$. This amount to precisely $4$ elements, namely $1,a,b,ab$. This group is called the Klein $4$-group, that is $$V_4=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^2=e\rangle\simeq C_2\times C_2$$